# How to use google speech API for audio having 2 channels

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We have audio recordings with 2 people speaking on different channels. I am trying the official documentation for node.js [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples). First of all, I got an error that the payload size was exceeding the maximum limit.

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxx:~/nodejs-docs-samples/speech$ node recognize.js async /home/ubuntu/output.wav
(node:18306) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Request payload size exceeds the limit: 10485760 bytes.
```

The documentation however, has just mentioned the limits in terms of recording length and not in terms of the file size. Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits)

Is there any workaround for this ?

Also, I tried with a smaller file size and got the configuration error:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/nodejs-docs-samples/speech$ node recognize.js async /home/ubuntu/output2.wav
(node:18291) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Invalid Configuration, Does not match Wav File Header.
Wav Header Contents:
Encoding: LINEAR16
Channels: 2
Sample Rate: 16000.
Request Contents:
Encoding: linear16
Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 16000.
```

I am not sure if the API allows usage of 2 channel audio input since I could not find any such config in the documentation. However, I found [this link](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/best-practices) where it is suggested to split the audio to individual channels and use them separately. What is the recommended way of doing this programmatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took this approach eventually

- Split the files to channels using `sox`
- upload both the channel audios to google cloud storage (for local files, speech API will not process if the recording length is over 1 minute. So if the files are big, they must be uploaded to google cloud storage)
- Pass each of the files through the speech recognition API
- Keep the transcripts as separate. There is no way we can merge the two since google speech API does not provide the timestamp for the words

Here is a helper function to split the files to channels

```
function splitFileToChannels (fileName) {
  let output = {
    channel1: `${fileName}_channel1.wav`,
    channel2: `${fileName}_channel2.wav`
  };
  let channel1Command = `sox ${fileName} ${fileName}_channel1.wav remix 1`;
  let channel2Command = `sox ${fileName} ${fileName}_channel2.wav remix 2`;
  return Promise.all([
    childProcess.execAsync(channel1Command),
    childProcess.execAsync(channel2Command)
  ])
  .then(() => {
    return output;
  });
}
```

Also, I had to convert the `mp3` file to `wav` format first before splitting to channels.

Comment: For future readers, some parts of this solution here is outdated due to beta changes in Google Speech-to-Text API, including word-level time codes, speaker diarization, and ASR on each channel.

See this for more details:
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multi-channel

However, there are still some issues with processing 2-channel wav files with the diarization tools.